# Grubrescue pops up and won't let me do anything

Tags: grubrescue

Okay so here is the deal:
My mother-in-law's ex boyfriend installed Ubuntu on her computer, due to the fact that she isn't very good with computers, I now have to install windows 7 on it.
I started the install after a long time trying to get the damn thing to boot from the disc. Halfway through something went wrong and it told me to retry. Now it pops up with whenever i try to boot from the CD again:

Error: unknown filesystem
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

I have formatted the drives, but somehow grub is still there (no idea how?)
Now how do I delete this stuff and install windows?

Comment: Instructions for booting to the Windows disk will depend on your computer's specifications, but it appears you go to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from a live Ubuntu or like Iso, go to Gparted. Windows can't access EXT and like partitions.
Try removing all partitions, remember to write changes to disk.
Shutdown, replace Ubuntu Iso with Windows Iso.
Boot. this should start Windows installer, just like on a new virgin harddisk!
  Beware all data will be gone!
Best of luck helping your mother.